# Multiple series into one line in line graph in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I'm trying to make a line graph in Excel that combines multiple series into ONE line. All I've been able to create so far is one graph with multiple lines on the same y axis. Is it possible to combine multiple data points from multiple series together in chronological order?

For context: I'm trying to make a graph that shows monthly temperatures between 1880-2017. January, February and so on, are each a separate series. I can make a bar graph that shows each year with each month chronologically but is there a way to convert this into a line graph without it producing multiple lines for each month, but instead one line that combines all the month data points together nicely?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create  a new column with averages for each month (using formula `=AVERAGE`) and plot this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there no gaps in the data you described, 
and you have a table
of `(2017-1880+1)=138` rows by `12` columns.
Here it is one way to make a one-line graph of the data
(some random imaginary data used in the example).

Unfortunately, standard `Excel` data functions can handle only 
dates not older than January 1, 1900, 
see for example, http://www.exceluser.com/formulas/earlydates.htm.

But you are lucky as all you need is just a year and a month numbers.
In this case the dates along the `x`-axis 
can be presented with numbers, which integer part is the year,
and fractional part is a fraction of the year that represents a month.

Assuming that the table is in `Sheet1!A2:M139`,
select <kbd>Sheet2</kbd> , type in a formula

```
=1880+FLOOR((ROW()-2)/12,1)+MOD(ROW()-2,12)/12
```

in the cell `A2`, and copy it down to `A1657` by any means you like.
For example, select `A2`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,
click in the `Name box` input field, 
type `A2:A1657` range in it and press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. 
That's it, this will create all the 
`x`-axis date values for the one-line graph.

Next step is to fill the range `B2:B1657` 
consequently with monthly data from the `Sheet1`.

Select cell `B2` and type in a formula

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2+LEFT(A2,4)-1880,2,,,"Sheet1")&":"&ADDRESS(2+LEFT(A2,4)-1880,13)))
```

select range `B2:B13`,
click at the end of the formula and press 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
The range `B2:B13` is now filled with the `T` data from `Jan` to `Dec` of 1880,
and it is still selected.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy this range,
then select `B14:B1657` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

That's it, all the readings from the table 
will be lined in the range `B2:B1657`.

[image]

**Edit**

There is even simpler solution for the second part:
fill the range `B2:B1657` with formula

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$M$139,FLOOR((ROW()-2)/12,1)+1,MOD(ROW()-2,12)+1)
```

It just converts a linear `x` coordinate of the current point,
based on the subsequent row number (`(ROW()-2)`) into  corresponding row, column pair
in the table and extracts the table value with `INDEX()` function.